# What should be the output of a double sumation over Kronecker delta?

Tags: kronecker-delta

> $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 \delta_{ij}\right)\left(\sum_{m=1}^3 \sum_{n=1}^3 \delta_{mn}\right)$$ eq. 1. Should be:

I am just confused because I am getting $3 \times 3$.

I was reading a book. It it stated that

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 \delta_{ij}\right)\left(\sum_{m=1}^3 \sum_{n=1}^3 \delta_{mn}\right)=81$$. Any advice? I am getting $3 \times 3$ Maybe the book is wrong. Just want to confirm.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: attached in a picture is the question

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! There are blind and visually impaired users of this site who use screen readers to interact with it. These screen readers can't extract information from images. Please update the question by typing the LaTeX of the equation from your screenshot.

Comment: I would agree: the answer is $3 \times 3$. Is there an answer you think it should be instead?

Comment: @Theo Bendit I edited the question. If you can confirm it. It will be very helpful!!

Comment: Ah, then you are very much correct, and the book is very much incorrect (barring any transcription errors). Each double sum being multiplied is summing the entries in the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix, which is indeed $3$.

Answer (score 1):

We just need to show that
$$\sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 \delta_{ij} = 3.$$
Expanding the summation terms, we get
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^3 (\delta_{i1} + \delta_{i2} + \delta_{i3}) &= (\delta_{11} + \delta_{12} + \delta_{13}) + (\delta_{21} + \delta_{22} + \delta_{23}) + (\delta_{31} + \delta_{32} + \delta_{33}) \\
&= (1 + 0 + 0) + (0 + 1 + 0) + (0 + 0 + 1) = 3.
\end{align*}